# add_header directives in location overwriting add_header directives in server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-headers

Using **nginx 1.2.1** I am able to use `add_header` under some circumstances.

**Here is a working example**:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /var/www;
    add_header Name1 Value1;      <=== HERE
    add_header Name2 Value2;      <=== HERE

    location / {
        echo "Nginx localhost site";
    }
}
```

The result

```
GET /
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Name1: Value1
Name2: Value2
```

**Here is something that doesn't work**: if I use the `add_header` directive inside `location`, the other `add_header` directives under `server` are ignored:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /var/www;
    add_header Name1 Value1;      <=== HERE
    add_header Name2 Value2;      <=== HERE

    location / {
        add_header Name3 Value3;  <=== HERE
        add_header Name4 Value4;  <=== HERE
        echo "Nginx localhost site";
    }
}
```

The result

```
GET /
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Name3: Value3
Name4: Value4
```

The [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) says that both `server` and `location` are valid `context` and doesn't state that using `add_header` in one prevents using it in the other.

**Q1: Do you know if this is a bug or the intended behaviour and why?**

**Q2: Do you see other options to get this fixed than using the [`HttpHeadersMoreModule`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule) module?**

Answer (score 28):

This is expected behaviour. The `add_header` directives, much like all other array-type directives in nginx, are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.

If you want nginx to add all headers in the `location /`, you have to list them all in `location /`, i.e.

```
location / {
    add_header Name1 Value1;
    add_header Name2 Value2;
    add_header Name3 Value3;
    add_header Name4 Value4;
    return 200 "";
}
```

If you need a way to list large subset of headers in a single place, you may use `include` directive for this.  See docs [here](http://nginx.org/r/include).

Comment: I only have `add_header` inside the `location` directive, but I still don't see this header added - any ideas?

Comment: @adityamenon Do you have only one `add_header`? If yes, then make sure a response code is one from docs, see http://nginx.org/r/add_header.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I had a couple different issues, I finally have a config that works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19135714/443219

Comment: Link to nginx docs explaining this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header